# Azure 2.3 SDK offline

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio, azure

Is there a way to get offline "Azure SDK 2.3" (VWDOrVs2013AzurePack.2E2.2E3) I'm behind a firewall and impossible to download. Same problem with (SSDTSetup) "SQL Server Data Tools".

I read there is no offline installer but is it possible to create one ?

Thanks,

Comment: Being behind a restrictive firewall myself, I constantly have similar issues. It would most likely be quicker to get a VPN connection than create a custom installer. There are many VPN services that cost just a few dollars per month.

Comment: I have a proxy, is there a way for force the installer to use this proxy ?

Comment: Proxy might work, but I am not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Azure SDK 2.3 can be download and manually installed from de following link:

[Windows Azure SDK for .NET - 2.3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42317)

I think SSDT for VS 2013 is an offline package, judging by the file size (1.1GB)

[Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42313)